# XCode Project Template

Tags: ios, xcode

When creating a new XCode project (iOS apps in Swift), I always repeat the same initial tasks, like:

- install CocoaPods
- change development language
- create folders hierarchy
- copy some source files and change a few lines
- install Crashlytics, etc.

I'd like to automate those tasks. The closest thing I found so far seems to be [xcake](https://github.com/jcampbell05/xcake) to generate project. As for the sources, I can bundle the frequently reused ones into a CocoaPod, but some code structure that I reuse needs to be outside of a pod and generated from a template. Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tool called Liftoff that automates XCode project creation:

https://github.com/liftoffcli/liftoff